# Aggregate function on categorical features with corresponding binary/ordinal features

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, binary, aggregate

I have a dataframe with startup data.

```
   company  exited  funding_rounds  funding_total   founders_have_degree
0      C1   0                 6           120.000                      1
1      C1   0                 6           120.000                      0
2      C2   1                 2           250.000                      1
3      C2   1                 2           250.000                      1
4      C3   0                 5            50.000                      0
```

"company" is the company name, but it can appear multiple times as each row holds information on specific employees too

"exited" is binary and 0 indicates that the company failed to exit, 1 indicates that it was successful.

"funding_rounds" is ordinal

"funding_total" stores the total amount of money raised and is of type (int)

"founders_have_degree" holds information about whether the founding team of the company has a degree, but each row is for a different employee. 1 indicates that the specific founder has a degree, 0 that he/she doesn't

--

How do I aggregate based on "company" so that each company appears only once, without adding up the "funding_rounds" number or the "funding_total", while summing the number of degrees of the founders?

I have tried this but this does not retain all the information I need:

```
aggregation_functions = {'founders_have_degree': "sum"}
df_new = df.groupby(df['company']).aggregate(aggregation_functions)
```

Desired outcome should be like so:

```
   company  exited  funding_rounds  funding_total   founders_have_degree
0      C1   0                 6           120.000                      1
2      C2   1                 2           250.000                      2
4      C3   0                 5            50.000                      0
```

Comment: you mean `df.groupby('company').agg({'exited':'first','funding_rounds':'first','funding_total':'first','founders_have_degree':'sum'})` ?

Comment: that works, thanks! Still don't understand how "first" works tbh, even after reading multiple explanations, but will do some more reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
df_new=(df.groupby('company').agg({'exited':'first','funding_rounds':'first',
                      'funding_total':'first','founders_have_degree':'sum'}))
```

---

```
         exited  funding_rounds  funding_total  founders_have_degree
company                                                             
C1            0               6          120.0                     1
C2            1               2          250.0                     2
C3            0               5           50.0                     0
```